# Why is this screw on the wing of DASH-8 Q400 sticking out, is it safe?

Tags: safety, wing, feature-identification, dash-8

Was flying with the Dash-8 Q400 and saw the screw sticking out? It's on the wing near the wheel compartment as shown in the picture.

Even if safe, it doesn't look pleasant to the passenger.

Are loose screws on those parts ever appropriate?

[image: Dash-8 Q400 engine nacelle]

Full image: https://freeimage.host/i/H4KfDQ4

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's not a screw, it's a drain line for the engine tail pipe, for fuel that can collect in the tail pipe during "wet" starts. There are other drains for the various engine and propeller gearbox vents, depicted [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/37398/what-is-this-on-the-starboard-engine-of-the-dash-8).

It's just a pipe with a disc welded to it. The disc is to reduce anything dripping out the opening from being blown back toward the surface of the nacelle, in the air stream.

Comment: It is possible to have it welded in discreetly so that it's not noticeable and anxiety provoking for the passenger? Never seen it before and am flying frequently.

Comment: Well it's always been there.  There's group of drains with a big flow control disc farther up. I added a link to another post that shows it.

Comment: @EugenSunic Drains must be there someplace, and as the last paragraph describes, need to protrude out away from the nacelle to avoid fluid stains on it from normal drainage. Being at the lowest point of the nacelle, they're easier to see on a Q400 than an A320 (for example), but every engine has one or more. At some point, there's a limit to how far the engineering can go to avoid creating (baseless) fears in nervous fliers. Solution: ask (as you did here) "is that normal?" and get the answer. No more concerns over this drain mast!

Comment: @EugenSunic I think it's rather unlikely that the design will be changed to match passengers' taste of design; even if it's possible.

Comment: @U.Windl Unless said passenger owns the manufacturer, then they can go about trying to justify spending multiple millions on it to get re-certified because "it looks scary".

Comment: @EugenSunic Would you have been less alarmed if "DRAIN OUTLET" was printed next to it?

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes, I should write an email to bombardier